# "Shape mismatch error" while swapping in numpy matrix

Tags: python-2.7, numpy

I am using python2.7 and numpy and I have the following matrix:

```
L = np.asmatrix([[0,1,2,3,4], [5,6,7,8,9]])
```

and I am trying to swap L[[0,1], 0] with L[[1,0], 0] but I have the error:

"shape mismatch: value array of shape (2,1) could not be broadcast to indexing result of shape (2,)"

I cannot understand this because if I print L[[0,1], 0] and L[[1,0], 0] they return

```
L[[0,1], 0] = matrix([[0]
                      [5]])
L[[1,0], 0] = matrix([[5]
                      [0]])
```

Anyway if I swap the entire row with L[[0,1], :] = L[[1,0], :] it works perfect but it isn't what I want to do.

Do you have any suggestion?

Comment: The error seems to be in a part of the code where you do the swap. Can you share with us how you swap the two values?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems to be an ugly behavior of the `np.matrix` class: if you write `L[[0,1], 0]` as an expression, you get a (two-dimensional) matrix back, but if you try to assign to `L[[0,1], 0]`, NumPy wants you to give it something one-dimensional!

The immediate way to solve this is to write the expression on the left as a two-dimensional slice, replacing the `0` in the second dimension with a slice `0:1`:

```
L[[0,1], 0:1] = L[[1,0], 0]
```

But you almost certainly just want to avoid using `np.matrix` entirely and just use `np.array`. The old NumPy matrix is an obsolete, someday-to-be-deprecated class. Arrays have the expected behavior, and you can just write this:

```
In [1]: L = np.array([[0,1,2,3,4], [5,6,7,8,9]])
   ...: L[[0,1], 0] = L[[1,0], 0]
   ...: L

Out[1]: 
array([[5, 1, 2, 3, 4],
       [0, 6, 7, 8, 9]])
```